# AJAX loaded PHP page have GET variables?

Tags: php, ajax, get

Is it possible for a PHP page, loaded by an AJAX call,

e.g. `$("#divid").load("phpfile.php");`

to have GET variables attached to it,

e.g. `$("#divid").load("phpfile.php?query=theman");`

That are then accessible within `phpfile.php` using `$_GET['query']`, which should return `theman`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you made an an AJAX GET request to phpfile.php?query=theman, you could access the value of query within your script like this:

$query = $_GET['query'];

Comment: if the main URL was something like `mainpage.php?query=asdf`, and the AJAX loaded PHP file was `phpfile.php?query=theman`, which value would `$_GET['query']` take, or would this be specific to where on the page it was?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use `$.post()` or `$.get();`

The first one uses post data.

```
 $.post(".", { query: 'theman' } ).done(function(data) {
   $('#div-to-fill').html(data);
 });
```

This one uses get data

```
$.get(".", { query: 'theman' } ).done(function(data) {
  $('#div-to-fill').html(data);
});
```